# Generate n equations in python solver

Tags: python, solver

I want to generate n equations to be solved in python 3 solver

I can solve by manually input how many variables. For example, 3 variables in the following.

```
ni = [1,2,3]
nb = [4,5,6]
rsV =10
S = [7,8,9]
n = len(ni)
from sympy import symbols, solve
A = symbols('a0:%d'%n)
equations = [
    Eq((A[0]+ni[0])*nb[0]/(rSv+(A[0]+ni[0])*nb[0]+(A[1]+ni[1])*nb[1]+(A[2]+ni[2])*nb[2]),S[0]),
    Eq((A[1]+ni[1])*nb[1]/(rSv+(A[0]+ni[0])*nb[0]+(A[1]+ni[1])*nb[1]+(A[2]+ni[2])*nb[2]),S[1]),
    Eq((A[2]+ni[2])*nb[2]/(rSv+(A[0]+ni[0])*nb[0]+(A[1]+ni[1])*nb[1]+(A[2]+ni[2])*nb[2]),S[2]),
       ]
sol = solve(equations)
```

I expect something like

```
n = len(ni)
from sympy import symbols, solve
A = symbols('a0:%d'%n)
for i in range (n):
    newsum=(rSv+(A[i]+ni[1])*nb[i])
    equations = [Eq((A[i]+d2sni[i])*nb[i]/newsum,S[i])]
sol = solve(equations)
```

Please note that the code above doesn't work properly because it only gives 1 result, rather than 'n' results, which is what I am expecting. This problem is just a problem about 'How to generate a n linear equations system based on how many unknown variables'. I ask this question because in each iteration, the number of unknown variables maybe different.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I ask my question in the 'expect sth like' part

Comment: ???I just want to know how to generate n equations

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: @Prune thanks for remind but I don't know how to improve my description. I am thankful if you could point out which part is unclear.

Comment: Your code doesn't highlight the problem.  You've written a loop to generate the wanted equations.  What isn't working?  A MCVE includes the desired result and the actual result.  You have implied what you want, but not what you got.  As far as I can tell, you generated the equations; you merely need to collect them into a list.

Comment: @Prune thanks for reply. I tested the part I am expecting, it only gives me one result (the last element in A), what I am expecting is 'n' results. Also, the result is wrong. So, I think I made some mistakes and looking for help. This is basic a linear system problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's because you specifically keep only the last one.  That problem has nothing to do with linear equations, only list handling.  Use `append`.

Answer (score 1):

You write over your `equations` variable each time you pass through the loop, so of course you will only get the last one.  If you want multiple equations you need to keep all of them.  One way to do so is to append them to a list like so:

```
n = len(ni)
from sympy import symbols, solve
A = symbols('a0:%d'%n)
equations = [] # set up equations list
for i in range (n):
    newsum=(rSv+(A[i]+ni[1])*nb[i])
    equations.append(Eq((A[i]+d2sni[i])*nb[i]/newsum,S[i])) # append instead of overwriting equations.
sol = solve(equations)
```